# Bootstrap Table - Full Screen doesn't work

Tags: bootstrap-table

I can see the Full Screen button with

`$(".table").bootstrapTable({
        showFullscreen: true,
 });`

But nothing happens when clicking on it...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add your code inside document ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".table").bootstrapTable({
        showFullscreen: true,
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn´t work in official examples:

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/boolean-options.html

Maybe it's unimplemented...